# Make bootable image from non-bootable to use with qemu

Tags: live-usb, virtualization, qemu, raspberrypi

I hope the question is not duplicate, I didn't find anything helpful by myself.
(And sorry for my english)

I have a new Raspberry Pi, and I need to install on it an os with some softwares.
I downloaded Raspbian on the official website (http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/)
No problem for that.

And since the Raspberry is slow, I have to launch the image of Raspbian on my computer, make modifications, save the new image, and put it on the the device via SD-card.

To launch the image, I am using qemu. I'm quite sure the configuration is OK, because I tried with an iso of Ubuntu and it worked well.

But, when I try to start Raspbian, qemu says it is not a bootable device.

And I didn't find a way to make a bootable iso (or a bootable img) from my non-bootable img without using usb or cd. So that's my question (yes, finally).

I have a non bootable .img and I need a bootable .img (not on a usb, not on a cd) to use qemu

How can I do ?

(I am using ubuntu 14.04)

Thanks you !

EDIT : the image was great, I just forgot the specific kernel for qemu... it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the image is correct, but qemu-system-arm can't launch it if we don't set an adapted kernel (with " -kernel kernel-qemu ")...

Now it's working, with the classic image (that seemed to be not bootable).